# Accessing <li> element with no class id using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, html-lists

I am trying to scrape the companies in the li in the ul table under final result. The source code looks like this

```
import string
import re
import urllib2
import datetime
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class AJSpider(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print ("initisizing")
        self.date = str(datetime.date.today())
        self.cur_url = "https://youinvest.moneyam.com/modules/forward-diary/?date={date}&period=month"
        self.datas = []
        print ("initisization done")


    def get_page(self,cur_date):
        url = self.cur_url
        try:
            my_page = urllib2.urlopen(url.format(date = cur_date)).read().decode("utf-8")
            my_soup = BeautifulSoup(my_page, "html.parser")

        except:
            print ('Failed')
        return my_soup

    def get_final(self, soup_page):
        temp_data = []
        final_result_section = soup_page.find("h3", text="Final Result")
        print final_result_section

    def start_spider(self):
        my_page = self.get_page(self.date)
        self.get_final(my_page)

def main():

    my_spider = AJSpider()
    my_spider.start_spider()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I found a similar quesiton in stackoverflow 
[Beautiful Soup: Accessing <li> elements from <ul> with no id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683475/beautiful-soup-accessing-li-elements-from-ul-with-no-id) ,  but this one here does have a class id, which makes things a lot easier.

In my scenario, how may I extract the li element from the ul table please? the only identifier here is really the content of the h3 tag, which is Final Result, however it is not a id so I have no idea how to make use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `h3` element *by text* and get the [following `ul` list](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
ul = soup.find("h3", text="Final Result").find_next_sibling("ul")
for li in ul.find_all("li"):
    print(li.span.get_text(), li.a.get_text())
```

---

Note that in the recent versions of BeautifulSoup, `text` argument was renamed to [`string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument), but they both work because of the backwards compatibility.

Comment: For the benefit of the person that asked the question, here's the two-line output from this code, for the fragment of HTML in the question:


01 Sep 16 Hays PLC [HAS]
01 Sep 16 Alumasc Group PLC [ALU]

Comment: Many thanks. I tried it, but I got TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments, and I tried both text and string, how this error is raised please?

Comment: @Victor looks like you are using `BeautifulSoup` 3 - if you have the following import: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`, you should upgrade! Install Beautifulsoup 4 via: `pip install beautifulsoup4` and change your import to `from bs4 import Beautifulsoup`.

Comment: I do use bs4 import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @Victor okay, edit the question and post your complete code please.

Comment: @Victor sure, you are returning `my_page` which from the `get_page` function, but `my_page` is not a `BeautifulSoup` instance. I think you meant to return `soup`.

Comment: Wonderful!! Silly me, I was experimenting and forgot to change this. Many thanks!

Comment: @Victor glad to help, see if you can accept the answer to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Comment: @alecx In fact, may I further ask a question please? is there a quick way to extract the text between [ ] please?

Comment: @Victor you would probably need some splitting, or apply a regular expression. Please consider creating a separate question if you need help with it. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe ok, many thanks, I will first spend some time to dig the solution and may create another question if necessary