# Trying to parse a webpage for latest high-ranking vulnerabilities using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I was trying to apply what others have suggested from here:

> [Beautiful Soup: Accessing <li> elements from <ul> with no id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683475/beautiful-soup-accessing-li-elements-from-ul-with-no-id)

But I can't get it to work. It seems the person from that question had a 
'parent' `h2` header, but the one I am trying to parse does not.

Here is the webpage I am scraping:

> https://nvd.nist.gov/

(I think) I located the element I need to manipulate, it's `<ul id="latestVulns">` and its following `li` sections.

I basically want to scrape for the section that says "Last 20 Scored Vulnerability IDs & Summaries" and based off of what the vulnerabilities are, send an email to the appropriate department of my work place.

Here is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://nvd.nist.gov/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')

section = soup.find('latestVulns')
print(section)
```

this code returns None

I'm at a loss

Comment: you need to do : find(id='latestVulns')

Comment: find specifies element to find such as ul, not an attribute. If you wanna find element by id use ```soup.find('ul', {'id':'latestVulns'})```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `find` expects the name of the element and you are passing in the `id`.

You can use this to find the tag correctly

```
section = soup.find('ul', {'id': 'latestVulns'})
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. Would you happen to know of a tutorial that I could follow on how to send emails with python? This is new territory for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python